# Failed to execute child process “'scriptName.sh” (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, shell, terminal, process, runtime

```
String command= "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper -e 'startDemonstrator.sh; bash'";
File workDir = new File("/home/malju/Desktop");
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, workDir);
```

After I execute this line of code I get the error above. My script is located in the Desktop folder. I already tried adding ./startDemonstrator and full path. I always get the error above. What can be the reason be?

I am just trying to open a sh script after the terminal is opened.

Comment: Please provide me the command that you use to execute manually. Is it like `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper -e 'startDemonstrator.sh; bash'`

Comment: @AbhijitPritamDutta do you mean when I open it with the terminal? I just go to the dekstop folder and open there the terminal and then I type in: ./startDemonstrator.sh

Answer (score 0):

First try like below:-

```
String command= "/home/malju/Desktop/startDemonstrator.sh";
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

If still not working try with below approach with ProcessBuilder.

```
    String result = "";
    String[] command = {"/home/malju/Desktop/startDemonstrator.sh"};
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
    Process p ;
    try {
        p = process.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        result = builder.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {   System.out.print("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it still didn't work.... "Failed to execute child process “/home/malju/Desktop/startDemonstrator.sh;” (No such file or directory)"

Comment: @kokos123, I have modified my answer. Now try

Comment: @Abijit I don't want to call the scirpt directly. I want to open the terminal and after the terminal was opened I want to execute the scirpt in my working directory